# F# comprehension loop vars mutable?

Tags: variables, f#, list-comprehension, mutable

In a list comp. e.g. is the variable used a real variable with same status as in a let stmt? If so it's actually mutable, right? It gets bound to a new something​ each time around the loop as right?

Answer (score 7):

No, it isn't a mutable variable.  We can see this by creating functions that we later invoke to print it.

Observe:

```
let printIs = [for i in 1..10 do yield fun () -> printf "%i " i]
printIs |> List.iter (fun f -> f())
```

This returns:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

Notice that each 1..10 value is printed, hence `i` cannot be a mutable variable because if it were, `i` would always have the value `10` after the loop was completed.  In reality, the symbol `i` refers to a different immutable value at every step in the list comprehension.

---

If I try and do this with an actual mutable variable `x`, I get different behaviour:

```
let mutable x = 1
let printIs2 = 
    [for i in 1..10 do 
        x <- i
        yield fun () -> printf "%i " x]
printIs2 |> List.iter (fun f -> f())
```

This returns:

> ```
> 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
> ```

Comment: But the "i" in your loop mutates doesn't it? It successively takes the values 1through 10.

Comment: @user1443098 No, it does not mutate.  If it did mutate, it would behave like the second example and print `10` every time because we print the values after the loop is already complete.  Rather, this tells you that `i` refers to a different immutable value at every step in the list comprehension.

Comment: Ah!  That's the bit I was missing! So, "i refers to a different immutable value at every"  Thanks so much!

Comment: I find it interesting that the equivalent code in Python produces different results: `printIs = [lambda : print (i) for i in range(1,11)]
;for f in printIs: f()` does indeed print 10 10's.  But that's because of Python's late binding behavior, IIUC,  By the time the lambdas are called, i has the value 10.

Comment: Nice answer. BTW: there was [a lot of confusion about variables bound in foreach loops in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) which led to a breaking change in version 5 of C#. The problem was not the same but very similar in nature.

Comment: @user1443098 in C# the result depends on the version of C# that you use.